# Modificar datos en la base de datos

Tags: php

No sé si tengo que poner todos los nombres de las columnas de la base de datos en el *UPDATE* pero así como lo tengo no me modifica nada en la columna de *file* la cual quiero ponerle un texto si las instrucciones se cumplen.

```js
// EN LA BASE DE DATOS 
// email | password | code

$email = '...';

if (//INSTRUCCIONES) {

$_UPDATE_SQL = "UPDATE $users SET code = 'texto aquí' WHERE email = '$email'";

}
```

Comment: ¿Tu tabla se llama $users? Porque hasta donde sé, $users podría ser una variable.  Sin mencionar que no veo que estes ejecutando la consulta ni que la estes parametrizando.

Comment: puedes tener varios errorres, lavariable $users puede no tener el nombre de la tabala correcta o tu variable email no es correcta

Answer (score 0):

En el código hacen falta muchas partes como para saber que estás haciendo...

Para hacer un UPDATE, necesitas tener una conexión, y saber que consulta quieres realizar.

Tu consulta es la sgte:

```
UPDATE $users 
SET file = 'texto aquí' 
WHERE email = '$email'
```

Lo que se traduce a:

```
ACTUALIZA la tabla $users ($users ahora mismo no existe hasta donde muestras)
COLOCA en la columna `file` lo siguiente (=) 'texto aquí'
DONDE el email sea (=) a la variable $email. (la cuál si tiene definida antes.
```

Ahora, esta consulta NO se está ejecutando...
Porqué, por que no sabemos si estás usando PDO, MYSQL, SQL, etc, para poder hacer la conexión y la consulta.

Deberías partir por dar esa info primero.

Comment: La tabla users si existe ya que en el archivo que estoy usando incluyo la apertura de la base de datos include('') que pues incluye la variable con el nombre la tabla.

Comment: Si pero si no pones todo el codigo, simplemente no existe... cual es el valor de `$users` entonces ???

Comment: Lo solucioné haciendo esto: mysqli_query($base,"UPDATE $users SET code = '' WHERE email = '$email'");

Comment: Como lo solucionaste ?? Si en este ejemplo no le estás dando valor a la columna code ???